# Storing props from parent function in a const variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am wanting to use a Formik form to edit data records that exist in a MySQL database.  The overall architecture I was planning was that a component would extract the data from the MySQL database and pass this data as array props to a child component which contains the Formik form.  I was then aiming to deconstruct those props to populate a const variable called initialvalues, which Formik uses to pre-populate the fields in the form.

I have retrieved the data I want to display in the form as an array using MembersByID.jsx below:

**MembersByID.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import MembersEdit from '../Members/MembersEdit'

function MembersByID(props) {
  
  const [memberData, setMemberData] = useState([])
  // console.log(memberData)

    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get( `http://localhost:3001/members/byId/${props.id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setMemberData(response.data);
      })
    }, [props.id])

  return (
      //next line takes props from DataTable.jsx - where the prop = id, which in turn equals the row id clicked in the table
        <>
      <div>Member ID No from MembersByID.jsx = {props.id}</div>
      <div></div>
      <MembersEdit memberData={memberData}/></>
  )
}

export default MembersByID
```

That component passes the member data as a prop called memberData to a child component called MembersEdit.jsx:

**MembersEdit.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup'; //yup does form validation
import axios from 'axios';
import { useMutation } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { PatternFormat } from 'react-number-format';


//react-query useMutation code
const useMembersCreateMutation = () => {
  return useMutation((formPayload) => {
    return axios.post('http://localhost:3001/members', formPayload);
  });
};

//Variable to store Tailwind css for 'Field' elements of Formik function
const formikField =
  'my-px block px-2.5 pb-2.5 pt-4 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg border border-gray-400 appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-blue-600 peer';

//Variable to store Tailwind css for 'Label' elements of Formik function
const formikLabel =
  'absolute text-base text-gray-500 duration-300 transform -translate-y-4 scale-75 top-2 z-10 origin-[0] bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 px-2 peer-focus:px-2 peer-focus:text-blue-600 peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-placeholder-shown:-translate-y-1/2 peer-placeholder-shown:top-6 peer-focus:top-1 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:-translate-y-4 left-1';

//Function for date fields formatting, using react-number-format
function DateField({ field }) {
  return (
    <PatternFormat
      {...field}
      format="####/##/##"
      mask={['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'M', 'M', 'D', 'D']}
      className={formikField}
      placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD"
    />
  );
}


//Main function - creates Formik form
function MembersEdit(props) {
  const { mutate } = useMembersCreateMutation();
  console.log(props)


  // //Formik initial values
  const initialValues = {
    forename: {props?.memberData?.forename},
    surname: '',
    date_of_birth: '',
    email_address: '',
    mobile_phone: '',
    address_1: '',
    address_2: '',
    address_3: '',
    address_4: '',
    address_5: '',
    postcode: '',
    doctor_name: '',
    medical_equipment: '',
    medical_conditions: '',
    next_of_kin_name: '',
    next_of_kin_relationship: '',
    next_of_kin_phone: '',
    next_of_kin_local: '0',
    key_safe_code: '',
    directions: '',
    deceased_date: '',
    normally_escorted: '',
    blue_badge_holder: '0',
  };

  // Yup field validation
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    forename: Yup.string()
      .required('*Forename is required')
      .max(35, 'Forename can be a maximum of 35 characters'),
    surname: Yup.string()
      .required('*Surname is required')
      .max(35, 'Surname can be a maximum of 35 characters'),
    date_of_birth: Yup.string().required('*Date of Birth is required'),
    email_address: Yup.string()
      .email('*Invalid email address format')
      .max(255, 'Email address can be a maximum of 255 characters'),
    mobile_phone: Yup.string().max(
      12,
      'Mobile phone can be a maximum of 12 characters'
    ),
    address_1: Yup.string()
      .required('*Address Line 1 is required')
      .max(35, 'Address Line 1 can be a maximum of 35 characters'),
    address_2: Yup.string().max(
      35,
      'Address Line 2 can be a maximum of 35 characters'
    ),
    address_3: Yup.string().max(
      35,
      'Address Line 3 can be a maximum of 35 characters'
    ),
    address_4: Yup.string().max(
      35,
      'Address Line 4 can be a maximum of 35 characters'
    ),
    address_5: Yup.string().max(
      35,
      'Address Line 5 can be a maximum of 35 characters'
    ),
    postcode: Yup.string()
      .required('*Postcode is required')
      .max(12, 'Postcode can be a maximum of 12 characters'),
    doctor_name: Yup.string().max(
      35,
      'Doctor can be a maximum of 35 characters'
    ),
    medical_equipment: Yup.string().max(
      255,
      'Medical Equipment can be a maximum of 255 characters'
    ),
    initial_medical_conditions: Yup.string(),
    next_of_kin_name: Yup.string().max(
      70,
      'Next of Kin Name can be a maximum of 70 characters'
    ),
    next_of_kin_relationship: Yup.string().max(
      40,
      'Next of Kin Relationship can be a maximum of 40 characters'
    ),
    next_of_kin_phone: Yup.string().max(
      12,
      'Next of Kin Phonecan be a maximum of 12 characters'
    ),
    key_safe_code: Yup.string().max(
      8,
      'Key Safe Code can be a maximum of 8 characters'
    ),
    deceased: Yup.string(),
  });

  // State used to display success/error posting message
  const [createMsg, setCreateMsg] = useState('');

  
  return (
    <>
{/* in the below, the two question marks mean it only attempts to get the prop value if it is not null */}
      {props?.memberData?.forename}


    <div className="createMemberPage px-5">
      <Formik
        enableReinitialize={true}
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={(values, formik) => {
          mutate(values, {
            onSuccess: () => {
              setCreateMsg('New Member Created!');
              formik.resetForm();
            },
            onError: (response) => {
              setCreateMsg('Error: Member not created - Keep Calm and Call Jonathan');
              console.log(response);
            },
          });
        } }
      >
        <Form className="formContainer">
          <h1 className="pb-3 text-xl font-semibold">General Information</h1>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="forename"
              placeholder=" " />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Forename</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="forename"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="surname"
              placeholder=" " />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Surname</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="surname"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="date_of_birth"
              placeholder=" "
              component={DateField} />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Date Of Birth</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="date_of_birth"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <h1 className="pb-3 pt-5 text-xl font-semibold">
            Contact Information
          </h1>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="email_address"
              placeholder=" " />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Email Address</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="email_address"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="mobile_phone"
              placeholder=" " />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Mobile Phone</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="mobile_phone"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="address_1"
              placeholder=" " />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Address Line 1</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="address_1"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="address_2"
              placeholder=" " />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Address Line 2</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="address_2"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="address_3"
              placeholder=" " />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Address Line 3</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="address_3"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="address_4"
              placeholder=" " />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Address Line 4</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="address_4"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="address_5"
              placeholder=" " />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Address Line 5</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="address_5"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="postcode"
              placeholder=" " />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Postcode</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="postcode"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <h1 className="pb-3 pt-5 text-xl font-semibold">
            Medical Information
          </h1>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="doctor_name"
              placeholder=" " />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Doctor Name</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="doctor_name"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="medical_equipment"
              placeholder=" " />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Medical Equipment</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="Medical Equipment"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="initial_medical_conditions"
              placeholder=" " />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Medical Conditions</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="initial_medical_conditions"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <h1 className="pb-3 pt-5 text-xl font-semibold">Next Of Kin</h1>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="next_of_kin_name"
              placeholder=" " />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Next of Kin Name</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="next_of_kin_name"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="next_of_kin_relationship"
              placeholder=" " />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Next of Kin Relationship</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="next_of_kin_relationship"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="next_of_kin_phone"
              placeholder=" " />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Next of Kin Phone</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="next_of_kin_phone"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <div className="pb-2">
            <label className="text-gray-500 px-2.5">Next Of Kin Local</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="next_of_kin_local"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
            <Field
              type="checkbox"
              value="1"
              className="border border-gray-400 rounded-lg outline-0 text-gray-500"
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="next_of_kin_local"
              placeholder=" " />
          </div>

          <h1 className="pb-3 pt-5 text-xl font-semibold">Other Information</h1>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="key_safe_code"
              placeholder=" " />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Key Safe Code</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="key_safe_code"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="directions"
              placeholder=" " />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Directions to Home</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="directions"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <div className="pb-2 relative">
            <Field
              className={formikField}
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="deceased"
              placeholder=" "
              component={DateField} />
            <label className={formikLabel}>Deceased Date</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="deceased"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
          </div>

          <div className="pb-2">
            <label className="text-gray-500 px-2.5">Normally Escorted</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="normally_escorted"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
            <Field
              type="checkbox"
              value="1"
              className="border border-gray-400 rounded-lg outline-0 text-gray-500"
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="normally_escorted"
              placeholder=" " />
          </div>

          <div className="pb-2">
            <label className="text-gray-500 px-2.5">Blue Badge Holder</label>
            <ErrorMessage
              name="blue_badge_holder"
              component="span"
              className="text-red-600" />
            <Field
              type="checkbox"
              value="1"
              className="border border-gray-400 rounded-lg outline-0 text-gray-500"
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="blue_badge_holder"
              placeholder=" " />
          </div>

          <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
            <button
              className="text-base text-white bg-blue-500 border hover:bg-blue-600 hover:text-gray-100  p-2 px-20 rounded-lg mt-5"
              type="submit"
            >
              Create Member
            </button>
          </div>
          <br></br>
          <h1 className={(createMsg === "") ? "" :
            ((createMsg === "New Member Created!") ? "text-xl text-blue-600 font-bold p-2 border border-blue-600 text-center" : "text-xl text-red-600 font-bold p-2 border border-red-600 text-center")}> {/* This code only formats the class, hence shows the border, when a message is being displayed  */}
            {createMsg}
          </h1>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    </div></>
  );
}

export default MembersEdit;
```

The props data arriving in MembersEdit is as follows, when logged in console.log:

[Props Data from console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzSjn.png)

As a test, I rendered one part of that props array in the return section of the MembersEdit function, using the line {props?.memberData?.forename}.  This renders on the screen OK.

Next, I tried adding the same line of code in the forename part of the initialValues const array, so in the part:

```
const initialValues = {
    forename: {props?.memberData?.forename},
```

But I then get a parsing error stating that a comma is expected:

[Parsing Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SspZr.png)

I'm not sure why the line of code: {props?.memberData?.forename} works when rendering the forename in the return section of the MemberEdit component, but not in the const array section.  Am I just making a simple syntax error of some description, or is my entire approach here incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here

```
props?.memberData?.forename
```

is a plain value - probably either a string or `undefined`.

When in the context of JSX, putting `{}` brackets around something indicates to interpret what's inside as a value to interpolate into the HTML. So doing

```
return (
    <>
      {props?.memberData?.forename}
```

works.

But that's only in the context of JSX. When outside of JSX, `{` indicates either the start of a block, or the start of an object literal. When in an expression context, it indicates the start of an object literal. Here, you're in an expression context:

```
const initialValues = {
    forename: // expression goes here
```

You don't need to interpolate anything, or create a nested object - you just need the *plain value* from props.

```
const initialValues = {
    forename: props?.memberData?.forename,
```

Doing

```
const initialValues = {
    forename: {props?.memberData?.forename},
```

fails because the `{` above indicates the start of an object literal, but objects require key-value pairs, and `props?.memberData?.forename` is only a value (an expression). For it to be valid syntax, it would need a key as well, such as `{ someKey: props?.memberData?.forename }`.

Another issue to consider is that optional chaining evaluates to `undefined` when the chain fails. You might want to account for that so that `forename` is set to the empty string if the chain fails, instead of `undefined`.

```
const initialValues = {
    forename: props?.memberData?.forename ?? '',
```